# Customizing the Fallback Policy message

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to customize the  default fall back message that rasa return

```
Did you mean Yes or no
```

but i couldnt find a good example or how i can ovveride is from the rasa sdk

Comment: You can take a look at: https://rasa.com/docs/core/0.10.4/fallbacks/ in combination with: https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/

Comment: i already saw that and i did ovveride ActionDefaultAskAffirmation class but it still show me the message did you mean yes or no

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/default-actions#action_default_fallback) `action_default_fallback`  which overwrites it. This action could look like the following:

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List

from rasa_core_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_core_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_core_sdk.events import UserUtteranceReverted


class ActionFallback(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_default_fallback"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        dispatcher.utter_message("Did you mean Yes or no")

        return [UserUtteranceReverted()]
```

Add the `action_default_fallback` to your actions in your domain file and add this to your endpoints file to connect Rasa Core and the Rasa Core SDK:

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Then run Rasa Core with the `--endpoints` flag and specify the endpoints file.

Comment: This  reference https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/about/ is broken, would you like to update this one?

Comment: Updated the link. Please note that the FallbackPolicy is deprecated in Rasa Open Source 2 and removed in Rasa Open Source 3.